# The attribute image.itemtype has an invalid value

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, structured-data

I am using `JSON-LD` format for **Structured data**. In home page `@type=website` & in details page `@type=Article`. `Logo` property of `Organization` section in details page showing following warning in **Google Structured Data Testing Tool** But home page is not although in both page value is same.

> http://kothaboli.com/media/1018/ka.jpg (The attribute logo.itemtype has an invalid value.)

**Home page `JSON-LD`**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "url": "http://kothaboli.com/",
    "name": ".....",
    "alternateName" : "....",
    "description" : "......",
    "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "http://kothaboli.com/search?keywords={search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
    },
    "sameAs":[
        "https://www.facebook.com/kothaboliDotCom/",
        "https://twitter.com/kotha_boli",
        "https://plus.google.com/+kothaboli"
    ],
    "publisher" : {
        "@type" : "Organization",
        "name" : "....",
        "alternateName": "...",
        "logo": "http://kothaboli.com/media/1018/ka.jpg"
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Google Testing Tool Result](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fkothaboli.com%2F)

**Details page `JSON-LD`**

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
    "@context" : "http://schema.org",
    "@type" : "Article",
    "url": "http://kothaboli.com/interviews/intellectual/arundhati-roy/",
    "name" : "... ....",
    "headline":  "...--’",
    "datePublished" : "7/26/2016 1:10:05 AM",
    "dateModified" : "8/12/2016 1:50:54 AM",
    "image" : "http://kothaboli.com/media/1088/33333333.jpg",
    "articleSection" : "....",
    "articleBody" : ".....’ ",
    "mainEntityOfPage": "..",
    "author" : {
        "@type" : "Person",
        "name" : "....",
        "alternateName": "Arundhati Roy"
        },
    "publisher" : {
        "@type" : "Organization",
        "name" : "...",
        "alternateName": "Kothaboli",
        "logo": "http://kothaboli.com/media/1018/ka.jpg"
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Google Testing Tool Result](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fkothaboli.com%2Finterviews%2Fintellectual%2Farundhati-roy%2F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want [Google’s Article rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles), you have to provide an [`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject) value (with `url`/`height`/`width`) for the `logo` and `image` properties. Currently you provide a URL value.

If you don’t want this feature (or you can’t get it because you can’t provide other required properties), you can keep your structured data like that.

Comment: Is it necessary to provide actual dimension of ImageObject or i can provide the dimension i want to show in rich result?

Comment: @ShishirMorshed: These are for the actual image. You can’t influence how the image should be displayed in the rich result.